# test continues to run in cypress runner after it fails, does not timeout

Tags: cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ujG2.jpg)

I have the following test in cypress:

```
    cy.visit('/main.html')
    cy.get('#homeTitle').contains('Welcome')
```

this passes.

If I change the contains value to "Welcome2" test should fail, and it fails in the runner, but the timer displayed continues to run, and it will not proceed to next test.

Seems like it doesn't time out or something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test that the element with id #homeTitle should contain the text message 'welcome' ? If so try this:

```
cy.get('#homeTitle').should('contain','welcome');
```

I don't quite understand your issue, but I will look harder.

Comment: Just came across this. I believe I'm experiencing the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788866/cypress-tests-continuously-run-xhr-posts-when-visiting-localhost-running-vue-js