# Cypress tests continuously run XHR posts when visiting localhost (running vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cypress

I'm relatively new to cypress, however, whenever I run `cy.visit` on localhost the XHR requests continuously run. This does not happen if I am visiting a remote URL. Here's the code:

```
describe('Applicant Login', () => {
  it('focuses input on login box', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/login')
  })
})
```

Cypress continually runs XHR requests over and over until I stop. I'm running a vue.js app via nuxt.js. Here's the log output:
[image: XHR keeps going and going ...]

I have no errors, no request or response info, the continuous requests.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe the XHR requests are triggered by the application; not by Cypress. To add more info, I see that the XHR requests are outcome of `cy.visit()` and I don't think it would harm your tests in anyway. You should be able to reproduce visiting the website in chrome browser and tracking the network requests.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that insight. You are correct. The request is coming from a logrocket plugin trying to reach its service. I hadn't noticed it in the network tab when using the application. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Kondasamy Jayaraman. The request is coming from a logrocket plugin trying to reach its service. I hadn't noticed it in the network tab when using the application. 
Much appreciation.